# Powershell - Create new line in CSV after a known value

Tags: powershell, csv, newline

I have a data set where when exported looks as a single line in a csv:

data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, data8

I would like to break this into rows and in this case I have a known value, so we will say data 4. Is there any way via Powershell that I can say if you see the term "data4" create a new line? example:

```
Original:
data1, data2, data3, constant value, data4, data5, data6, constant value

Desired:
data1, data2, data3, constant value
data4, data5, data6, constant value
```

I figured this would be easy and after looking I have only found one other answer where they had a somewhat complicated regex to do this. Any help would be appreciated. I have tried a number of things but generally my entry just ends up as text in the csv or red error messages mocking my lack of powershell knowledge. Would even be okay if I lose the constant value - its just trash from the export, but a good sorting spot to know when the next line should start.

Comment: Does your Csv have headers?

Comment: maybe you could do it like this ``$string -replace '(?<=constant value),\s+', "`n"``

Comment: I am getting errors testing this. I could be building the query wrong though as it wants the string element to be first. "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split by verbatim field value `data4`, assuming that field is a row-*interior* field:

```bash
# Create sample CSV file (without a header)
@'
data1, data2, data3, constant value, data4, data5, data6, constant value
data7, data8, data9, constant value, data4, data11, data12, constant value
'@ > test.csv

(Get-Content -Raw test.csv) -replace ',\s*(?=data4,)', [Environment]::NewLine
```

Pipe to `Set-Content -NoNewLine` to save to a file.

See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/w1iphS/1) for an explanation of the [regex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) and the ability to experiment with it.

Comment: I have tried the above a number of times/ways/variations and no matter what it just outputs as a one row csv again. Appreciate the suggestion, but just not getting it done for some reason.

Comment: @PatrickMayer, the above sample code works for me in both PowerShell editions. Does it not work for you? If it does, your sample data isn't representative of your actual data.

Comment: @PatrickMayer, if it produces only a single line _overall_, the implication is that you forgot to use `-Raw` with `Get-Content`.

Comment: In this case it does not work. Perhaps there is something with the data I am not explaining well. Going to keep messing with it. It drops everything as a single line output. I have tried this a number of ways - so perhaps there is some nuance that is missing? Only thing different that I have done that is consistent is providing a save location at the end, so | Set-Content -NoNewLine clean.csv

Comment: Below is what I ran after doing the @' content '@ to strip headers. 

(Get-Content -Raw ./test.csv) -replace ',\s(?=DetailsEntitlements,)', [Environment]::NewLine | Set-Content -NoNewLine test4.csv

Comment: @PatrickMayer, if you can post a link to (sanitized) _representative_ sample data, I can take a look. Note that you're using `\s`, which matches exactly _one_ whitespace character. If you know the whitespace to be a space, it's better to use ` ` (or ` *` for zero or more spaces). If your `test.csv` has multiple lines and you read it with `Get-Content Raw`, there's no explanation for why  you would end up with only a single line in the output file.

Comment: Because it wasn't working I did another export of the data to be sure everything was clean and now it is working. Not sure if something I did previously broke it as I don't ever recall putting the content back to the original - but now its working. Appreciate the help and sticking with it

Comment: Glad to hear it all worked out, @PatrickMayer; my pleasure.